# Some customers are receiving an address message upon PayPal Chekout

Tags: php, paypal

Some customers are receiving this address message upon check out. 
[See attached screen print](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BV1Uf.jpg) "There's a problem with your address please return to the merchant and update including your city, state and zip code.

I can not not repeat the error on any of my devices and not all my customers are receiving the error. I do not see pattern to a particular device or browser.

I have tried setting address_override to value=1 and passing in the address. I have tried value=0  without passing in address information...  I have left the address_override statement out all together.

I am struggling on finding information on the cause of the error message to my customers.  My customers tell me that their address is correct in our database.

Please point me in a direction to correct this error it is causing much frustration for my customers. Much Appreciation in advance!

I am creating my button using HTML:

```
    <form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" id="payNow" style="float:right; margin-right:40px;">
                <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick">
                <input type="hidden" name="business" value="<?php echo $buinessEmail; ?>">
                <input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="<?php echo $itemName; ?>">
                <input type="hidden" name="amount" value="<?php echo number_format($amtDue, 2); ?>">
                 <input type="hidden" name="on0" value="<?php echo $myItems; ?>">
                <input type="hidden" name="os0" value="ParentID=<?php echo $parentID; ?>">
                <input type="hidden" name="invoice" value="<?php echo trim($cartID);?>">
                <input type="hidden" name="return" value="<?php echo $home; ?>MyThankYouPage.php; ?>">
                <input type="hidden" name="notify_url" value="<?php echo $home; ?>MyPayPalIPN.php; "/>
                <input type="hidden" name="cancel_return" value="<?php echo $home; ?>BackToMyCart.php;">
                <input type="hidden" name="add" value="1">
                <!-- Autofill Paypal form for customer  *** Causes problems for some customers ***  
                        0 — prompt for an address, but do not require one
                        1 — do not prompt for an address
                        2 — prompt for an address, and require one
-->
                <input type="hidden" name="address_override" value="0">
 <!--               <input type="hidden" name="address1" value="<?php //echo trim($row['Street']);?>">
                <input type="hidden" name="city" value="<?php //echo trim($row['City']);?>">
                <input type="hidden" name="state" value="<?php //echo trim($row['State']);?>">
                <input type="hidden" name="zip" value="<?php //echo trim($row['Zip']);?>">
                <input type="hidden" name="first_name" value="<?php //echo trim($row['FirstName']);?>">
                <input type="hidden" name="last_name" value="<?php //echo trim($row['LastName']);?>">
                <input type="hidden" name="email" value="<?php //echo trim($row['email']);?>">   -->
          <!--      <input type="image" id="paypalBtn" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/webstatic/en_US/i/buttons/checkout-logo-medium.png" border="0" name="submit" style="margin-top:2%;" alt="Check out with PayPal"> -->
                <input type="image" id="payNowBtn" src="Images/Buttons/CheckOutBtnGreen.jpg" border="0" name="submit" style="margin-top:2%;" alt="Check out with PayPal">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that it had nothing to do with the Address.  The address error message was a "standard" type message set to the user from PayPal.  The problem was in my on0 variable.
it is limited to 64 characters.  I was passing more than 64 characters.

Once I corrected the problem our users no longer get the address error message.  Thank you to Zac at PayPal who found the problem!  Once he told me the problem, what I was seeing made sense ...I was all the larger orders that had difficulty.

Answer (score 0):

You should add some more hidden fields with address fields like given below:

```
  <input type="hidden" name="address1" value="9 Elm Street">
  <input type="hidden" name="address2" value="Apt 5">
  <input type="hidden" name="city" value="Berwyn">
  <input type="hidden" name="state" value="PA">
  <input type="hidden" name="zip" value="19312">
```

Comment: Thank you.  I have tried it with and with out the address.  It makes no difference for some users.  The majority of our customers can proceed to the PayPal check out with no problems.  A few of them get the Address error message. I can not repeat the response to make any corrections.

Comment: Then you have to check what's the difference in the other data between those who succeeded and those who didn't. Probably the users who has some different IP from different zone might be creating the problem.